# Analyzing Excel Data

Tags: excel, analytics

I'm stuck in a project where I need to analyze some data out of an Excel sheet. The data is supposed to be sorted by dateTime, because any rows with a dateTime somewhat close to eachother (e.g. within a minute to five minutes) are to be read as a multi of the same instance and preferably to be copied to a second sheet. Concretely, sheet 1 looks like this:

ID - dateTime - ad.inf.1 - ad.inf.2 - ad.inf.3 
1 - 16:06:04 
2 - 18:04:34 
3 - 18:04:56 
4 - 18:05:06 
5 - 18:16:59

Somehow, I'd like to have it identify row 2-3-4 as a trifold of 1 instance (as ad.inf.2-3 will be the same, ad.inf.1 MAY vary) and list it on sheet 2 as

ID - instanceAmount - ad.inf.2 - ad.inf.3 
 
1 - 3

What would be the best way as to try and realize this?

Comment: Write out how you would do this manually, then convert it to code or worksheet functions.  If you run into problems with your code, edit your question to show the problem.

Comment: Sort the data by `timeDate` then add a helper column to see if two adjacent values are less than 5 mins apart. Finally, use the subtotal option to split out each group of > 5 mins

Comment: @RonRosenfeld and where would I find how to write such worksheet functions? I haven't worked with this type of "coding" before.

Comment: @Ciphra Excel HELP, Google, Macro Man's suggestion, etc.  There are also numerous published books available on how to use Excel.  Failing all that, I suppose you could hire an Excel expert to accomplish your task.